# PostgreSQL/PostGIS/pgRouting function (written in PL/pgSQL) not found nor run in user but can be used and gives correct result by admin

Tags: pgrouting, function, plpgsql

A function using `pgr_dijkstra` (pgRouting) is returning correct answer when run from "admin".
The same function run from a simple user returns an error (`ERROR:  function pgr_dijkstra(unknown, integer, integer, boolean) does not exist`).

Complementary information:

```
admin - mydb> select * from pgr_version();

 version │  tag   │   hash    │ branch │ boost
═════════╪════════╪═══════════╪════════╪════════

2.6.2   │ v2.6.2 │ b14f4d56b │ master │ 1.59.0
(1 row)
```

But from user with all privileges granted I get:

```
user - mydb> select * from pgr_version();

ERROR:  **function pgr_version() does not exist**

LINE 1: select * from pgr_version();
```

Using, \df though, the function appears (exists)...

Same search_path for both user and admin, 2 different roles though for admin and user.
But user can access all tables on the schema used (select, insert, update, delete) and can execute all functions in that schema.
I am perplexed.

Query in function:

```
SELECT seq, d.node, d.edge, cost,
       e.geom as edge_geom,
       n.geom as node_geom,
       n.station
FROM
    pgr_dijkstra( '
        SELECT gid AS id, source, target, length AS cost
            FROM london_tube.lines',
        ( SELECT station_id
                        FROM london_tube.stations WHERE station = 'Finchley Road'),
        (SELECT station_id
                        FROM london_tube.stations WHERE station = 'Piccadilly Circus'),
                false
        ) AS d
        LEFT JOIN london_tube.lines AS e ON d.edge = e.gid
        LEFT JOIN london_tube.stations AS n ON d.node = n.station_id
ORDER BY d.seq;
```

Comment: Th GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA my_schema TO my_user; This allows the execution of functions but not the access to tables..

Comment: What about the schema where pgRouting is installed? The user must have it in its path and have usage rights + exectute privs on the functions (if not public)

Comment: Thanks to @Mapperz and JGH. It was actually an incomplete set of privileges to the pgRouting resource. I add to grant all on both schema (where pgRouting was installed), tables, sequences and functions.